# BetterTouchTool & MSFT Remote Desktop (aka RDP)

Tags: remote-desktop, bettertouchtool

When I use Microsoft Remote Desktop from my MBP I would like to map certain Command key combos to their ALT equivalents

In this example Cmd-F12 should be delivered as Alt-F12 to the windows machine.  When I create that mapping in Better Touch Tool the app on the Windows app only recognizes the key as just F12

[image: See Screenshot of BTT config]

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "Alt-F12" on windows do?  I don't know of any particular function that is assigned to.  Also, if memory serves me correctly, the Alt key is to the right of spacebar on the Mac keyboard.  Can you distinguish between right and left on BTT?

Comment: Alt-F12 is used by one of my specific Windows apps, not global (even tho my mapping here would always map it while in  remote-desktop)
There are alt keys on both sides of the keyboard, I'm not sure of the significance tho